# Are the drivers in the preboot environment for ESXi different than post? "No devices with free space"

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have an old Dell Precision I used to run ESXi on. Went to reinstall it, the installer sees both drives in it just fine on both 7.0u3 and 8.0.

[image]

However, after installation on the NVMe drive, post boot, I go to create a new datastore on the 3.64TiB drive and it's not there.

[image]

Windows was just on the host so I am certain that the drive both exists and is in proper working condition.

Note: I am not asking about the HAL or device compatibility. I am asking what the delta is between the preboot environment and post since the drives show up in the preboot environment.

### Update

Maybe something about partitions? I reinstalled except installed to the 3.84 TiB drive instead of the NVMe drive and now they both show up? I'm not sure why unless the datastore manager choked on some pre-existing partition that used to be there.

[image]

Comment: Idk if I understand the scenario exactly, but I get the impression that the key word here is *free*. I guess there are partitions that fill the device, and that you may need to clear that up (under devices) before this step?

Comment: Updated the OP with additional info and a picture